# MVC Where condition on children (hasMany)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I want to do a where on an objects' children. So for example:

Model schoolclass has children, I want the schoolclass with only the children named Hank

```
Model Schoolclass
    int ID
    string Classname
    virtual ICollection<Children> Children

Model Child
    int ID
    int ClassID
    string FirstName
    string LastName

this.db.Schoolclass.Where(sc =>
    sc.ID == 4 &&
    sc.Children.FirstName == "Hank"
).FirstOrDefault();
```

but child can not be accessed directly, 'cause it's a hasMany relationship.

Do I have to use something like Any?

This way I query the received data (but I don't need all the children, that's overhead)

```
Schoolclass = this.db.Schoolclass.Where(sc =>
    sc.ID == 4)
.FirstOrDefault();

Schoolclass.Children = Schoolclass.Children.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Hank").ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you including the `sc.ID == 4` condition in your expression? Does the `SchoolClass` with ID 4 have any children?

Comment: Yes the SchoolClass has 20 children and 2 named "Hank", I want that class with the two children

Answer (score 1):

"I want the schoolclass with all children named Hank":
`this.db.Schoolclass.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.Children.All(c => c.FirstName == "Hank"));`

Comment: I think this will get the schoolclass if all children are named hank or else return null

Comment: Okay, if I see my question now, maybe I asked it wrong, question rewrited, it now says: with only the children named "Hank"

Comment: `All` means that all children of class should have name "Hank".

Comment: I can't imagine any class in reality having all its children/students with the same First name. It may never happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
this.db.Schoolclass.Where(sc =>
    sc.ID == 4 &&
    sc.Children.Any(x=>x.FirstName == "Hank")
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or simpler:

```
this.db.Schoolclass.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.ID == 4 &&
                       sc.Children.Any(x=>x.FirstName == "Hank"));
```

Comment: Really? Surely to get all children whose property equals something.. you should remove the `sc.ID == 4 &&` part.. since that side of the expression is extremely limiting in itself.

Comment: I tink I will get the schoolclass with all his children when there is a child named Hank, when there is no child named Hank schoolclass will be null

Comment: @SimonWhitehead do you really understand what the OP wants? The expression has nothing wrong, the first `sc.ID==4` selects the school, the second `sc.Children.Any` will check if that school has any children with `FirstName` being `Hank`. If you remove the first condition, **it will search all the schools** and return the first one meeting the second condition.

Comment: @KevinvanHoorn from your comment, the code above should return the schoolclass you want.